# Como eliminar un dato dentro del mismo index en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Trabajo en Laravel 5.7, tengo un Modelo Locations, un controlador LocationsController, y al ser tan pocos datos los que va a tener este modelo (y su respectiva tabla en la base de datos) he decidido hacer su respectivo crud en el mismo index mediante ventanas modales, el problema es que al traer todos los datos con un foreach, la variable que uso para traer dichos datos queda con la información del ultimo objeto que se mostró, por lo que al usar el metodo edit o destroy desde el mismo index, solo me permite eliminar y editar el ultimo objeto de la tabla

Tabla que muestra los datos
.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($locations as $location)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$location->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->nombre}}</td>
            <td><button onclick="window.location='./locations/{{$location->id}}/edit'" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></td>
            <td><button onclick="document.getElementById('modalConfir').style.display='block'" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Boton de eliminar que esta dentro de la ventana modal:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['locations.destroy', $location->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Eliminar', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer que esto funcione correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo puede ser jugar con onclick para pasar el parámetro al action del formulario, una idea rápida es:

```js
function deleteLocation(e) {
  let deleteForm = document.getElementById('location_delete');
  deleteForm.action = 'https://miruta.com/' + e.dataset.locationid;
  console.log(deleteForm);
  // mostrar modal
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deleteLocation(this)" data-locationid="100" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>

<button onclick="deleteLocation(this)" data-locationid="25" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>

<form id="location_delete" method="DELETE">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Esto en términos de blade y Laravel Collective sería algo así:

```
<button onclick="deleteLocation(this)" data-locationid="{{$location->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>


{!! Form::open(['route' => ['locations.destroy', $location->id], 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'location_delete']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Eliminar', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: En el código de la pregunta también se está abriendo con JavaScript...